# Pullback of local diffeomorphism takes closed covector fields to closed ones

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is Corollary 11.46 from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

Suppose $F: M \to N$ is a local diffeomorphism. Then the pullback $F^*: \Xi^*(N) \to \Xi^*(M)$ takes closed covector fields to closed covector fields.

Proof. $\omega$ is a closed covector field if it satisfies for some smooth chart $(U, (x^i))$, and writing $\omega = \omega_i dx^i$ in coordinates,
$$\frac{\partial \omega_j}{\partial x^i} = \frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial x^j}. $$

It says in the text that if $(U, \varphi)$ is any smooth chart for $N$, then $\varphi \circ F$ is a smooth chart for $M$ in a neighborhood of each point of $F^{-1}(U)$. In these coordinates, the coordinate representation of $F$ is the identity, so if $\omega$ satisfies the above condition in $U$, then $F^*\omega$ also satisfies it in $F^{-1}(U)$.

I am having difficulty actually proving this statement. Suppose we have $(F^{-1}(U),(y^j))$ for the proposed smooth chart in $M$. Then we need to find the coordinate representation of $F^*\omega$ in these coordinates. So we have $F^*\omega (\partial / \partial y^j) = \omega dF(\partial / \partial y^j) = \omega(\frac{\partial \hat{F}^i}{\partial y^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}) = \omega(\partial / \partial x^j) = \omega_j$. So we end up with $F^*\omega = \omega_i dy^i$. But then $\omega_i$'s are functions in $N$, whereas $y^i$ are charts in $M$, so this doesn't make sense. What is wrong here?

Comment: A $1$-form $\omega$ is closed precisely when the exterior derivative $d\omega=0$. A fundamental fact is that $d$ commutes with pullback. So $d(F^*\omega) = F^*(d\omega) = F^*(0) = 0$.